# Problem with downloading applications from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, flash

This is my first time using Linux. I own two, black hat and Ubuntu. I decided to install Ubuntu. it appears to be working fine with exception of two items I like to fix.

When I try to launch Ubuntu software from icon it flashes up and disappears. The exec. is working but the app dies immediately and when I try to download anything not just Ubuntu software but apps like Adobe flash, it pops up a small window asking for launch application apturl.

What does this mean, what tool am I looking for and where do I get it since Ubuntu store won't help.

Comment: Sorry tech info follows;  (might be helpful)

Comment: I posted an answer for the first part of your question. apturl is just a tool for downloading and installing packages, and I don't quite understand what problem you have with it. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry tech info follows;  (might be helpful)  ubuntu 16.04  memory 3.8gb  processor intel 2.0 duo 2.10ghzx2 grphics gm45 express chip set  OS 64bt disk 153.3gb on a think pad t400

Comment: the problem is when on the internet i try to download any applications it pops a window up asking for apturl and to choose one but when i search for one it shows nothing on the system to use. so i feel that im missing some type of tool

Comment: this is what i found on terminal;                          AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Did you run the other command I suggested? Can you now open _Ubuntu Software_ successfully?

Comment: why yes i can thank you but i still have the problem with no tool for apturl window that popos up

Comment: I'd suggest that you reboot. Then, next time the apturl window pops up, you should be given the option to select _Ubuntu Software_ (which is a proper tool for the purpose).

Answer (score 0):

As regards the problem with Ubuntu Software, I think it can be fixed if you make sure you have the latest version of all packages. Open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+T and run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: why yes i can thank you but i still have the problem with no tool for apturl window that pops up

Comment: @TimG: Did you notice my latest comment above?

Comment: yes i did and i followed your instructions and it had fix the ubuntu software program but did not resolve my problem for downloads. when i click on anything i want to download a window pops up asking to choose a apturl but i cant find a tool to complete the down load. you mentioned "apturl is just a tool for downloading and installing packages" but did not tell me how to aquire the tool.

Comment: @TimG: I think you need to show us better what it looks like. Can you please take a screenshot and add it you your question by editing it.

Comment: /home/teekaho/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-12-10 20-49-47.png          i dont know if this worked let me know

Comment: /home/teekaho/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-12-10 20-49-47.png              /home/teekaho/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-12-10 20-57-28.png

Comment: @TimG: No, I can't access a file on your computer. Please edit your original question and upload the screenshot file.